# Add a back bar Button between view controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, back-button

I have the following problem. I have the following VC structure

NC-> A->B-->C-->D-->E->F

Where NC is my navigation controller directly connected (->) with the VC A, which is also directly connected with VC B.

Depending on a parameter by tapping on a button in VC B my app decide to go to VC C or to stay in B (-->). I can't therefore, as done before, construct a direct connection between the button and the VC. So I implemented this transaction in VC B.

My problem is that doing like this I do not have a back button on VC C to eventually go back to B. How should I solve this issue?

Thanks?

Comment: When you push the view controller to the navigation stack it should have a back button.

Comment: please add your code which is added in VC B to redirect to VC C

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed no, I have no navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CAN** create connection between view controllers. In your situation, simply connect B and C with a segue type push. Then when every you want to do this segue, simply call

```
//Do some code to decide if you want to call this or not
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: nil)
```

In this way, when you get to your VC C, you will have a default back button to VC B from your top level NC

For example

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. by using your method I get an error.
My code to go from B to C is the following

//let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartVC")

//self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @sky90 Check my example. You only need these two steps. You don't have to programmatically create segue like what you are currecntly doing

Comment: HEY it works now!!! Thank you so much! I spent so many time on it!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sky90 No problem man, I'm so happy that I have this screen recording tool :)